# Including boolean property check in Search Query builder with Grails Searchable Plugin

Tags: grails, lucene

I am trying to limit my search criteria to return entities with a boolean property set to true. For example

```
class Product {
  def name
  Boolean enabled
}
```

How can I do it using a search query builder, my simple search so far is:

```
Product.search(query, analyzer: 'whitespace')
```

I tried using query builder with term but it does not work:

```
Product.search {
  must(queryString(query))
  must(term('enabled',true))
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you try putting it in the query? e.g. `+enabled:true +name:foo`. This will help determine if there is a problem with how it's being indexed etc.

Comment: Adding +enabled:true works properly and does not return the results with enabled set to false

Comment: If this issue has been solved, somebody should post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 0.5.5.1 version of searchable plugin. After updating to the latest 0.6 SNAPSHOT enabled field is being picked up like it supposed to and results are accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be the spelling error ("available" vs. "enabled").

According to [this thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Searchable-Plugin-How-to-Limit-Indexing-to-Sub-Set-of-Domain-Instances-td1561051.html) anyway, your syntax is correct.

Comment: I made an error here but the actual code is correct, updated my question as well. Thanks.